# How to change the pixel to percentage using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

```
 var mapWidth = $(this).data('width') ? $(this).data('width') : 100;
```

i would like to make 100 px in % . i try '100%' but is not work. Any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to change the `data` attribute as you are apparently trying with your code - you want to change the `width` attribute:

```
$(this).width('100%');
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to select the element itself before you can use `$(this)`
you can do this by using `$('type'), $('#id') or $('.class')` after that you want to alter it's CSS, not it's data.

So a general example would be (using an element with ID "map":

```
$('#map').css('width', '100%');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `.css()` [jQuery function](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Hope it helps! ;)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('#width_val').on('change', function() {
    var width_val = $(this).val();
    $('#div_example').css('width', width_val + '%');
  });
});
```

```css
#div_example {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="width_val" min="0" max="100" value="0">
<div id="div_example"></div>
```